# How to remove same number after tokenize use group-by in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I am trying to remove duplicate number after tokenize the value and another entry value e.g. `<p>1(a), (b), (c)</p>` and `<p>1(a)</p>`. How to remove duplicate entry using **group-by**.
**Input XML**

```
<root>
    <p>1(a), (b), (c)</p>
    <p>1(a)</p>
    <p>2(a)</p>
    <p>3(a)</p>
    <p>1(c)</p>
</root>
```

**Expected Output**

```
<root>
   <p>1(a)</p>
   <p>1(b)</p>
   <p>1(c)</p>
   <p>2(a)</p>
   <p>3(a)</p>
</root>
```

**XSLT Code**

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="p" group-by=".">
            <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains(current-grouping-key(), ', ')">
                    <xsl:variable name="tokens" select="tokenize(current-grouping-key(), ', and |, ')"/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="$tokens">
                        <p>
                            <xsl:value-of
                                select="if (starts-with(., '('))
                                then replace(head($tokens), '(.*)\(.*?\)$', '$1') || .
                                else ."/>
                        </p>
                        
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <p><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></p>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might suffice to use

```
  <xsl:template match="root">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each 
            select="distinct-values(
                      p ! 
                      (let $tokens := tokenize(., '\s*,\s*') 
                           return (head($tokens), tail($tokens) ! (substring-before(head($tokens), '(') || .)))
                    )" expand-text="yes">
              <p>{.}</p>
          </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6q1SDkG

Comment: Sir, I am trying adjust this code but not given proper output Can you check this code [link](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6q1SDkG/1)?

Comment: @Sam, please ask a new question where you explain the details in the question, it doesn't make sense to complicate the requirements by simply posting a link to some sample with a much more variable input data and without detailing the result you want and the logic behind the input -> output mapping.